# Live time SQL schedule

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an ms sql database with a table

> (Speeches)

. The columns  are

> (Speechid(auto increment), SpeechName(varchar), Speech_Date(date),
>   SpeechTime(varchar)).

As you see I know the date of the Speech and the start time of every Speech.

I don’t know the End time. I want to create a query that will be refreshed from an asp.net/c# page every 2 minutes and will presents what Speech is on stage right now (live time). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To automatically refresh the page use this>>

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```

Or

In On_Load event write,

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "15")
```

in On_Load event only take the current time from system by this>>

```
try
{

    string curr_time= DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    da=new SqlDataAdapter("select SpeechName from Speeches where SpeechTime<'"+curr_time+"'",conn);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.fill(ds);
    for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    string speechName=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].toString();//This will give you last speech within that time.

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Compare it with time values in database, by this you will be able to find current speech.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how can I determine if I am inside the duration of a speech.

Comment: @Equilibrium kindly see my edited answer u will get Logical help

Comment: Thank you, but your code seems to present only the last speech I have in the database table(I checked it with a multiline textbox).  If I have 3 speeches that on stage, (deferent stages run simultaneously) right now. How I can present them?

Comment: Then you have to add another field to database such as Ending time and each time update the database table when the speech has been ended. By this way you will come to know current speeches in case of simultanious one.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. To add a column is not an option. I don’t have the permition to do it. Is there any way to a)short the speechtime ascending, b) find the nearest time from now and the next one, c)determine for how long I am in this duration. 
Please consider that this is a predetermined schedule. So it is mandatory the speeches have a sequence. Ex (10:00am, 10:10am, 10:20am….)

Comment: Then you have to work on assumptions like one person will finish his speech within an hour. then only you will be able to go through the options which you have mentioned in your last comment.